# How to check if list of word are in string and they are near each other? [Python]

Tags: python, substring, string-matching, python-re

I have a string and a list of words:

```
string ="""Ventilation box with reference VE03 with soundproofed box with inspection door
with the following technical characteristics: Air flow: 250 l s Available static pressure:
200 Pa With voltage regulator With characteristics according to project technical data
sheets Model make: CVB 4 180 180N or equivalent Includes flexible anti-vibration tarpaulins
at the air connections and metal dampers and supports Includes cable."""

list1 = ["CVB","1100","250"]
list2 = ["CVB","4","180","180N","RE","147W"]
```

I want to check if the string has 2 or more words from the list and if they are near each other (for example 5 positions/words before and after). Using 'list1' has to be false cause 'CVB' and '250' aren't together, but using 'list2' should return true ("CVB","4","180" and "180N" are together).

My actually function only detects if has the word in the string:

```
count = 0
for word in list1: 
        if len(re.findall("(?<!\S)" + word + "(?!\S)", string)) > 0:
            count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: The requirements are unclear. If there are any two words from the list near each other in string then return True? Is that right? What is near each other? Separated by " "? What about separated by ", " or ". "?

Comment: Should return True if contains 2 or more word and they are near each other (5 word of distance before or after). The list is separted by "  ".

Comment: Why are you splitting `list 1`, which already a list?

Comment: True, I'm editing.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
from itertools import combinations
def my_function(my_string, list1):
    list_to_search_in = my_string.split()
    indices = []
    for word in list1:
        if word in list_to_search_in:
            indices.append(list_to_search_in.index(word))
    comb = combinations(indices, 2)
    for pair in list(comb):
        if abs(pair[0] - pair[1]) <= 5:
            return True
    return False
```

Also check your naming conventions and avoid things like `string` or `list` as variable names.

Comment: I don't think that would work with punctuation though.

Comment: I try with my 'list1' and 'list2' but both get True. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think I found the bug in my initial code: The two nested loops over the indices list means the same index can show up as index1 and index2, meaning the subtraction in that pair results in 0, and that triggers True to be returned. What we need to do is to check every index only against the other indices but not itself. I'll edit my code to fix that.

Comment: Okey Schnitte. Thank you for your help! I didn't expect so many answers, so now I have so many approaches to test.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider utilizing [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations


def any_close_words(text: str, words: list[str], dist: int) -> bool:
    words = set(words)
    word_to_positions = defaultdict(list)
    for index, word in enumerate(text.split()):  # Could consider using a nltk tokenizer...
        if word in words:
            word_to_positions[word].append(index)
    for w1_positions, w2_positions in combinations(word_to_positions.values(), r=2):
        for a in w1_positions:
            for b in w2_positions:
                if abs(a - b) <= dist:
                    return True
    return False


def main() -> None:
    string = """Ventilation box with reference VE03 with soundproofed box with inspection door
with the following technical characteristics: Air flow: 250 l s Available static pressure:
200 Pa With voltage regulator With characteristics according to project technical data
sheets Model make: CVB 4 180 180N or equivalent Includes flexible anti-vibration tarpaulins
at the air connections and metal dampers and supports Includes cable."""
    print(f'{any_close_words(string, ["CVB", "1100", "250"], 5) = }')
    print(f'{any_close_words(string ["CVB", "4", "180", "180N", "RE", "147W"], 5) = }')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
any_close_words(string, ["CVB", "1100", "250"], 5) = False
any_close_words(string, ["CVB", "4", "180", "180N", "RE", "147W"], 5) = True
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems this works and has the parameter distance. Don't know if this is more slow than @R. Baraiya answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def chk(string, lst):
    ls = string.split(' ')
    for i,s in enumerate(ls): #lOOP on all string list
        if s in lst:          # checking if word is it in the additional list
            if len(set([ls[i-1],s,ls[i+1]]).intersection (lst))>2: #Next creating the list by before/after word list such as [make:, CVB, 4 ] if and additional list will have 2 or more same element return true 
                return True
    return False
chk(string, list2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems works. I will test this and @Sash Sinha answer.